# Meteor Jira POST call

Tags: angularjs, post, meteor, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to adjust the transition (the status) of an issue in Jira with a POST call. I'm running a Meteor application with a Meteor Backend and a Angular frontend.

```
Meteor.methods({
performPostCall: function(id, status){
    var transitionObject = {
        "transition": {
            "id": "11"
        }
    }; 
    var result = HTTP.call('POST', 'https://privateurl/rest/api/2/issue/' + id + '/transitions', 
        {data: transitionObject}, 
        {headers :{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ******',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }});

    return result;
}
});
```

In my frontend, I call the meteor method and handle the callback like this:

```
Meteor.call('performPostCall', id, status, function(error, success){
                if(error){
                    alert(error);
                } else {
                    alert(success);
                }
            });
```

When I press the button that fires the meteor method call, it will this strange and lovely error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ddp--0266-remoteserverurl/sockjs/info?cb=4bxmv_smgg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'remoteserverurl' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

But I declared this 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the header, so I don't understand why it is complaining. Can somebody tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) third parameter should be an object with fields required to make a call, in your code `data` and `headers` are different objects.

Proper syntax would be :

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'https://privateurl/rest/api/2/issue/' + id + '/transitions', {
  data: transitionObject, 
  headers :{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ******',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }});
```

Also, result variable is most likely undefined since you try to do it in synchronous fashion, POST call is asynchronous, make use of fourth parameter (callback) to pass data to client, like:

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'https://privateurl/rest/api/2/issue/' + id + '/transitions', {
  data: transitionObject, 
  headers :{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ******',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }}, function (error, result) {
    if (!error) {
      return result;
    }
  });
```